# How to automate TeamCity installation using docker?

Tags: docker, automation, teamcity

[JetBrains TeamCity docker image](https://github.com/kennedyoliveira/jetbrains-teamcity-docker) describe build steps for already installed TeamCity.

Is there any way to automate installation of TeamCity it-self?

For example creating the admin account, enabling standard authentication and setting up the project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Automation of installations like this can often be done with config management tools.  GitHub and the public repos for these tools is a good place to start.

There is a Puppet installer for TeamCity here: https://github.com/haf/puppet-teamcity

Here's a Chef cookbook:
https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/chef-teamcity

You can also use tools like Packer to generate your image(s).  Packer can substitute for a Dockerfile in generating a Docker image. Packer will also run Provisioners (including Chef/Puppet/Ansible) to configure your image.